# Dropbox API v2 to find the files that are synced, moved, renamed, copied and deleted

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

Dropbox API in Java provides methods to upload files, read content of a file etc. But is there a way to find whether the files inside the Dropbox are synced, deleted, moved, copied or renamed using Dropbox APIs?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Dropbox-API-v2-to-find-whether-the-files-are-synced-deleted/m-p/279495#M16773 ]